# Highcharts donut pie/legends position

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So im having a hard time figuring out how to set up the layout for the pie/legend positions. I want the legend to be aligned to the left, and the pie aligned to the right. 40/60 percentages -ish.

like so:

[image]

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            type: 'pie',
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text : '',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                {
                    name: "first",
                    y: 23
                },
                {
                    name: "second",
                    y: 8
                },
                {
                    name: "third",
                    y: 11
                },
                {
                    name: "fourth",
                    y: 11
                },
                {
                    name: "fifth",
                    y: 47

                }
            ],
            size: '100%',
            innerSize: '67%',
            showInLegend: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    })
```

Comment: share your code that you have tried

Comment: Its just a basic init of a donut pie..

Answer (score 15):

How about just adding the `legend` to the chart options, as stated by the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend)?

```
legend: {
    align: 'left',
    layout: 'vertical',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: 40,
    y: 0
}
```

which renders this:

[image]

the rest you can do with CSS styling